# emacs auto-complete-c-headers closing hook

Tags: emacs, code-completion

I'm new on emacs.I followed a tutorial on youtube for emacs as ide for c/c++
but there are some step that do not work fully for me : the auto-complete for c-headers.

I installed  yasnippet and auto-complete for C/C++ headers.

I get the normal auto-complete behavior for  `#include <stdio.h`  but `>` closing hook  is   not added even if  I type tab on `h`

Others,  `#include <float`    ,    is not completed with `.h>`,
`#include <ctype.h>`  call just `isdig` not `isdigit` as I want

```
; start package.el with emacs
(require 'package)
;add MELPA to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
;initialize package.el
(package-initialize)
;start auto-complete with emacs
(require 'auto-complete)
;do default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
;start yasineppet with emacs
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
;let's define a function which initializes auto-complete-c-headers and gets called for c/c++ headers hooks
(defun my:ac-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'achead:include-directories '"/usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include")
)
;now let's call this function from c/c++ hooks
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
```

Something is missing ?
The path for headers comes from `gcc -xc++ -E -v -`

```
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the configuration for C. However, I saw that you use the `auto-complete` mode in your init file. Can you try the [company-mode](http://company-mode.github.io/) instead. In my opinion, it's way more efficient than the `auto-complete` mode